# Is mysql datetime not compatible with strtotime()?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm passing this function a mysql datetime and it is returning nothing. Is mysql datetime not compatible with strtotime()? I assume that the foreach loop is ending and the return variable is not being called, but why?

```
function timeAgo($time) {
    $time = time() - strtotime($time); // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = array (
        1 => 'second',
        60 => 'minute',
        3600 => 'hour',
        86400 => 'day',
        604800 => 'week',
        2592000 => 'month',
        31536000 => 'year'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'').' ago';
    }
}
```

**Update** This is the code that gets it from the database, there are no quotes in the datetime string.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
   $commentTime = $row["time"]; 
   $commentComment = $row["comment"]; 
   $commentCommenter = $row["commenter"]; 
}
```

And this is the code to echo it: `echo '<h3 class="party-time">'.timeAgo($commentTime).'</h3>';`

Comment: What is the value of $time, passed to function?

Comment: Some advice, make your constants as `60*60` as hour, `24*60*60` for day, etc. That way, a mistake is easily spotted and others understand it easier.

Comment: "2013-08-28 04:15:27" is in $time

Comment: If the double quotes are in the string, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code that gets the info from the database?

Comment: Less than 10 rep can't post an answer, but here is the code: This is the code that gets it from the database, there are no quotes in the datetime string.

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $commentTime = $row["time"];
     $commentComment = $row["comment"];
     $commentCommenter = $row["commenter"];
    }

And this is the code to echo it:

    echo '<h3 class="party-time">'.timeAgo($commentTime).'</h3>';

Comment: please show the value of `$time` at the time when the function `timeAgo` is called

Comment: Posted the $time variable above. I don't know what I did but now the function is returning a negative value. What the hell?

Comment: You keep overwriting the `$commentTime` variable...

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a timezone issue. I was manually setting the date in the SQL server I was using which set the datetime to my local time, but the server's timezone was -3 hours, causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot tell what `$time` holds exactly, but when you feed an [ISO-8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to `strtotime`, it works fine:

```
php > echo strtotime("2013-08-01 12:00:00");
1375351200
```

Comment: This is what's in $time "2013-08-28 04:15:27". And the function is still not working.